# hsqldb sqltool rcfile does not work

Tags: hsqldb

I can run the command-line SqlTool for HSQLDB to connect to a database and run a SQL statement using the **--inlineRc** option (and specify the database url/user/password), but I can't get it to work using the **--rcFile** option (with url/user/password in a file).  What am I missing here?

This works:

```
java -classpath /hsqldb/2.3.2/hsqldb-2.3.2.jar:/hsqldb/sqltool/2.3.2/sqltool-2.3.2.jar org.hsqldb.cmdline.SqlTool --sql "\dt" --inlineRc url=jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:8887/myDb,user=sa,password=
```

The result of the "\dt" command is a list of the database tables:

```
TABLE_SCHEM  TABLE_NAME
-----------  -----------------------------
PUBLIC       USERS
PUBLIC       USER_ADDRESS
PUBLIC       USER_PHONE
```

This doesn't work:

```
java -classpath /hsqldb/2.3.2/hsqldb-2.3.2.jar:/hsqldb/sqltool/2.3.2/sqltool-2.3.2.jar org.hsqldb.cmdline.SqlTool --sql "\dt" --rcFile /hsqldb/setup/sqltool.rc
```

The result is:

```
SEVERE  Error at '--sql' line 1:
"\dt"
We are not connected to a Data Source, but one is required for this action
org.hsqldb.cmdline.SqlTool$SqlToolException
```

And the **/hsqldb/setup/sqltool.rc** file contains:

```
# This is for a hsqldb Server running with default settings on your local
# computer (and for which you have not changed the password for "sa").
urlid mydbid
url jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:8887/myDb
username sa
password
```

I've tried numerous variations; using a space between parameters or an '=' between parameters, putting all the parameters on one line exactly like the --inlineRc option, naming the file sqltool.rc (the default) and putting in my user home directory (default location), etc.  I've read through the documentation several times here:

[Chapter 1. SqlTool](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/util-guide/sqltool-chapt.html)

Nothing seems to work. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out why the --rcFile argument wasn't working.  I needed to specify the **urlid** on the command line, typically as the last argument. The --help option does actually show this, but since it's not required when using the --inlineRc option, I assumed it wasn't necessary. It *is* necessary when using the --rcFile argument. My lack of understanding of how the RC file works.

The RC file can contain several database connection definitions, each identified by **urlid**.  When using the --rcFile argument on the command line I needed to specify *which* urlid in the rcFile has the parameters for the database connection, even if there is only one defined.  Using the above **/hsqldb/setup/sqltool.rc** example, the command line to run the SqlTool and list all the tables ("\dt") should look like this:

```
java -classpath /hsqldb/2.3.2/hsqldb-2.3.2.jar:/hsqldb/sqltool/2.3.2/sqltool-2.3.2.jar org.hsqldb.cmdline.SqlTool --sql "\dt" --rcFile /hsqldb/setup/sqltool.rc mydbid
```

Unfortunately, not excellently documented at [hsqldb.org](http://hsqldb.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Give the `--help` switch.  That shows the needed syntax.  The very first example in the documentation which you read several times says:

```
java -jar $HSQLDB_HOME/lib/sqltool.jar --help
```

Comment: Yes, I tried --help numerous times. That's how I knew there was an "--rcFile" option, which you can see under "This doesn't work".  As I said, I tried it with and without "=" on the options; in other words, neither "--rcFile=/path/to/rcfile" nor "--rcFile /path/to/rcfile" worked. I posted the contents of the rcfile to see if the format was wrong, and I used = between the parameters and tried it without. Nothing works. Why?

Comment: java -jar /local/hsqldb/lib/sqltool.jar --rcFile=tempsqltool.rc --sql='\dS' m