# hsqldb sqltool.jar with sqltool?rc fille connects but a \j command does not worrk

Tags: debian, hsqldb

I want to connect to a new hsqldb database with the sqltool.jar. I have read and tried commands from the chapter 16 of the hsqldb guide. and this question [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35641860/hsqldb-sqltool-rcfile-does-not-work)
My config is the following:
classpah set with the HSQLDB_HOME/lib
I have created a hsqldb user as owner and run commands from /home/hdsqldb,
the sqltool.rc file is copied in this directory and only one urlid localhost-sa is present, with
url jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost
username sa

The following (from hsqldb home) works
java -jat /opt/hsqldb/hsqldb-2.7.2/hsqldb/lib/sqltool.jar localhost-sa

Then in the sqltool cmdline, I want to get an external hsql connection to the db0 (thus creating it)

```
\j "jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost;databaseName=db0;"
```

Which does not work (I have tried only two times (now I cannot connect via java -cp ... sqltool.jar any more)

```
Disconnect from JDBC Data Source
org.hsqldb.cmdlije.SqlFile$BadSpecial: Failed to connect
    at org.hsqldb.cmdline.SqlFile.processSpecial(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.cmdline.SqlFile.scanpass(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.cmdline.SqlFile.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.cmdline.SqlTool.objectMain(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.cmdline.SqlTool.main(Unknown Source)
Caused By: java.net.MalformedURLException: url string is required to establish connection, but is null 
    at org.hsqldb.cmdline.utilclone.RCData.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.cmdline.utilclone.RCData.getConnection(Unknown Source)
```

I would like to try another url form in \j but,as I said I cannot connect any more to sqltool interface. Here is what I get

```
Failed to get a connection to 'jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:1234/db0 as user "sa"
Cause: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

I will try from another more recent machine but i I am grateful for any help (since two days)
```

I am running from
Linux XX 3.16.0.4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.16.43-2+deb8u5 (2017-09-19) i686 GNU/Linux
tournesol 59

Comment: You describe trying to connect to an HSQLDB server instance but it seems you never started the server. If you intend to connect to an HSQLDB file database instance in-process, then a URL such as "jdbc:hsqldb:file:/opt/dbs/mydb' is ueed

Comment: I already tried exactly what you wrote (in -process) and it worked. Thanks